# How to pass props to React stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-props

I am doing navigation in the following manner Home.js -> discover-things.js(which includes a top nav-bar) -> Filter-screen.js

In Home.js,I have a stack navigator defined like this---

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import DiscoverScreen from './discover-things';
import TopNavBar from './discover-things/top-nav-bar';

export default StackNavigator({
  DiscoverScreen: {
    screen: DiscoverScreen,
    navigationOptions: { header: TopNavBar },
  },
});
```

In the top-nav-bar, I have this---

```
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

export default ({...props}) => (   //Here the props are undefined
  <View style={styles.navbarContainer}>
    <View style={[styles.titleContainer, globalStyles.verticallyBottom]}>
      <Text style={styles.discoverTitle}>
                Discover
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={[styles.toolsContainer, globalStyles.verticallyBottom]}>
      <View style={[styles.toolsInnerContainer, globalStyles.verticallyBottom]}>
        <Icon name="search" size={25} style={styles.icon} />
        <Icon name="sliders" size={25} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('FilterScreen')}
/>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Here I am applying an OnClick on one of the icons, so that It can lead me to the filter screen.

In Filter Screen, I have this----

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import FilterScreen from './view';

export default StackNavigator({
    FilterScreen: {
        screen:FilterScreen,
        navigationOptions: {header : null}
    }
})
```

But on click of the icon in the filter screen, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here and how to correctly implement it?

Comment: Have you tried passing the props to View directly. May be like `<View style={styles.navbarContainer} {...props}>`

Comment: yes doesn't work @aelor

Comment: can you check and see what `this` is at this point in console.log. Also check what `this.props` returns

Comment: Probably, you might be looking at `props.navigation.setParams` ? which you could use as `props.navigation.state.params`.

Comment: also try `(props) => { ... }` instead of spread it first, `({props}) => { ... }`. so you'll get to know what exactly is coming in the component.

Comment: You might find this information useful https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/876#issuecomment-302945124